# Excel - Filter With 150 Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Column in Excel 2016 with approx. 500 unique values. I want to filter on 150 of these.

How can I filter by these values other than clicking on each of the 150 unique check boxes? I will need to do this with multiple spreadsheets. Manually doing this is time consuming and prone to error.

Can I do this with a custom filter? Write vba code? Other?

Comment: Use advanced filters where you can specify range of cells https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4113-excel-filter-based-on-list-selection.html  or searche for advanced filters in excel.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your needs is `Advanced Filtering`. If you go to `Data > Sort&Filter` you will find a button called `Advanced`. In there you can set two things:

1) **List Range**, where you highlight the entire range you want to filter on

2) **Criteria Range**, which is where your 150 filters would go.

This should filter out any value that is not part of the Criteria Range and works in a few second for each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You've offered no indication on where the 150 unique values come from but if you can find them and stuff them into an array, a regular AutoFilter command can use them in the Criteria1 argument with Operator:=xlFilterValues.

```
dim arr as variant

arr = array("value1", "value2", "value3", ...)

with myrange

  .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=arr, operator:=xlfiltervalues

end if
```